# delete button for current division in HTML using javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removeclass

I made a dynamic form with an add button that creates a new division with the clone of the form but has a different ID. However, I also want to have a delete button with each division that removes the division that it is in, including the button itself.

I am familiar with JQuery `.remove()` method but I am having trouble selecting the division that the button is in.

```
<div id="attendees">
        <div id="att1" class="attendee">
            <form name="droplist" action="html_form_action.asp" method = "get">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><span class="legend">Filter</span></legend>
                    <label for="select">Category: </label>
                    <select id="select" size="1"  >
                        <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
                        <option value="employees">Number of Employees</option>
                        <option value="hits">Hits on TechCrunch</option>
                        <option value="time_founded">Time Founded</option>
                        <option value="total_money">Total Money</option>
                    </select>

                    <div id='radioContainer' style="display:block;">
                        <input type="radio" id="condition"  name="button" value="more"/> <label for="condition"> > </label></br>
                        <input type="radio" id="condition1"  name="button" value="less"/> <label for="condition1"> < </label>
                    </div>

                    <div id='radioContainerTime' style="display:block;">
                        <input type="radio" id="condition2"  name="button" value="later"/> <label for="condition"> After </label></br>
                        <input type="radio" id="condition3"  name="button" value="earlier"/> <label for="condition1"> Before </label>
                    </div>

                    <div id = "text_box" style="display:block;">
                        <label for="input_value">Amount: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="box" name="input_value" value="textIn" />
                    </div>
                    <button>remove</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="add">Add more</a>
</div>​
```

My JavaScript so far is this:

```
$(function(){
 var template = $('#attendees .attendee:first').clone(),
     attendeesCount = 1;

 var addAttendee = function(){
     attendeesCount++;
     var attendee = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){
         var newId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.length-1) + attendeesCount;
         $(this).prev().attr('for', newId); // update label for (assume prev sib is label)
         this.name = this.id = newId; // update id and name (assume the same)
     }).end() // back to .attendee
     .attr('id', 'att' + attendeesCount) // update attendee id
     .prependTo('#attendees'); // add to container
 };

 $('.add').click(addAttendee); // attach event
 }); 

$("button").click(function () {
  $this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the `<div class="attendee">` that contains the button, you can just use this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
     $(this).closest(".attendee").remove();
     return(false);
});
```

This looks up the parent chain from the clicked button to find the first part with a `class="attendee"` and then removes that.

---

FYI, I'd strongly suggest putting a class on your delete button because it's a little dangerous to hook up to ALL buttons in your page.

To put a class on your delete button, change the HTML to this:

```
<button class="deleteButton">remove</button>
```

And, change the jQuery to this:

```
$(".deleteButton").click(function () {
     $(this).closest(".attendee").remove();
     return(false);
});
```

The `return(false)` prevents any default action in the form from occurring based on the click.

Comment: how would I put a class on my delete button?

Comment: also, when I make this change, the button takes me to the new page indicated by the form "action" element which I dont want it do to.

Comment: @Santiago - I've addressed both your questions at the end of my answer.